# RSS (Receive Side Scaling) on Intel XL710 Per port

Tags: network-programming, intel, dpdk

I struggle with Intel XL710 card using DPDK to make it compute RSS hash using only SRC IPV4 or DST IPV4 on per port basis. 
The card has 4 10GE ports and RSS config is global for them whatever i do. I tried to set SRC/DST IPV4 fields in PCTYPE and the configuration applied **last** only takes action.

So the behavior i want to achieve.

Let's say i have upstream packet arrived on port 0:

**SRC: 10.10.10.1** and **DST:10.10.10.2**

And reply downstream packet arrived on port 1:

**SRC: 10.10.10.2** and **DST:10.10.10.1**

I want port 0 (which in our case is **upstream**) on the card to compute RSS hash based on  **SRC** address **10.10.10.1** and for, port 1 (which is **downstream**) to compute the hash using **DST** address which in our case also will be **10.10.10.1**. So the idea is to distribute packets between RX queues in a way that only SRC/DST address respectively affects this distribution.

I'm not bound specifically to RSS. Whatever tech will do if it allows to achieve this.

The configuration i used:

```
void setFilter(uint16_t portId, uint32_t value){

//Value = RTE_ETH_FLOW_NONFRAG_IPV4_TCP in that case

struct rte_eth_hash_filter_info info;
uint32_t ftype, idx, offset;
int ret;

if (rte_eth_dev_filter_supported(portId,
            RTE_ETH_FILTER_HASH) < 0) {
    printf("RTE_ETH_FILTER_HASH not supported on port %d\n",
                        portId);
    return;
}

memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));
info.info_type = RTE_ETH_HASH_FILTER_GLOBAL_CONFIG;
info.info.global_conf.hash_func =
  RTE_ETH_HASH_FUNCTION_DEFAULT;

ftype = value;
idx = ftype / UINT64_BIT;
offset = ftype % UINT64_BIT;
info.info.global_conf.valid_bit_mask[idx] |= (1ULL << offset);
info.info.global_conf.sym_hash_enable_mask[idx] |=
  (1ULL << offset);
ret = rte_eth_dev_filter_ctrl(portId, RTE_ETH_FILTER_HASH,
                RTE_ETH_FILTER_SET, &info);
if (ret < 0)
    printf("Cannot set global hash configurations by port %d\n",
                        portId);
else
    printf("Global hash configurations have been set "
           "succcessfully by port %d\n", portId);
}

void setPctypeRss(uint16_t portId, uint16_t fieldIdx) {

/* Note that AVF_FILTER_PCTYPE_NONF_IPV4_TCP is define for
 * Virtual Function. Defines are the same for Physical Functions
 */
int ret = -ENOTSUP;

enum rte_pmd_i40e_inset_type inset_type = INSET_HASH;
struct rte_pmd_i40e_inset inset;

ret = rte_pmd_i40e_inset_get(portId, AVF_FILTER_PCTYPE_NONF_IPV4_TCP,
                             &inset, inset_type);

if (ret) {
    printf("Failed to get input set.\n");
    return;
}

memset(&inset, 0, sizeof(inset));

ret = rte_pmd_i40e_inset_set(portId, AVF_FILTER_PCTYPE_NONF_IPV4_TCP,
                 &inset, inset_type);

if (ret) {
    printf("Failed to CLEAR input set.\n");
    return;
}
else
{
    printf("Successfull cleared input set\n");
}

ret = rte_pmd_i40e_inset_get(portId, AVF_FILTER_PCTYPE_NONF_IPV4_TCP,
                 &inset, inset_type);
if (ret) {
    printf("Failed to get input set.\n");
    return;
}

ret = rte_pmd_i40e_inset_field_set(&inset.inset, fieldIdx);

if (ret) {
    printf("Failed to configure input set field.\n");
    return;
}

ret = rte_pmd_i40e_inset_set(portId, AVF_FILTER_PCTYPE_NONF_IPV4_TCP,
                 &inset, inset_type);
if (ret) {
    printf("Failed to set input set.\n");
    return;
}

if (ret == -ENOTSUP)
    printf("Function not supported\n");
}
```

Comment: RSS is the way to go. Show us the configuration you have tried so far?

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy added configuration code, hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

IMO it is worth trying a bit simpler solution. We can simply use `rte_eth_dev_configure()`:

https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__ethdev_8h.html#a1a7d3a20b102fee222541fda50fd87bd

And just set `eth_conf.rss_conf.rss_hf` to `ETH_RSS_IP` as described here:

https://doc.dpdk.org/api/structrte__eth__rss__conf.html#ad70f17882a835e5d4e38c64a9f872fdc

There are few examples in DPDK using this functionality. and most of them work fine ;)

Comment: Thanks for reply! I tried that config also, but it doesn't allow to use different fields of IPV4 header per PHYSICAL port on the NIC for RSS hash computation. You only can make it symmetric but it seems there's no way to force RSS to compute hash for physical port 0 using only SRC and for physical port 1 using only DST at least on XL710.

Comment: @toozyfuzzy did it work? Do you want to make a per-server local state structure?

Comment: nope, it affects all ports =( I need this cause my device has "client" entity which identified by it's IPV4 configured on this device. So i want to direct all flows with that IPV4 to the same lcore for processing. Device has loads of that "clients" each with unique IPV4

Comment: "RSS field selection is done globally and cannot be configured differently per PF or VF." Source: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/xl710-10-40-controller-spec-update.pdf

Comment: I am not sure how many clients you have, but note that Flow Director has its own limits... I guess the most reliable and portable solution would be a software distributor, i.e. a dedicated core for packet classification and forwarding to a specific RX queue for other cores to process. Unless the symmetric RSS will suit your needs...